# Overloading << operator with mapped value in a map container

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, dictionary, g++

Im having trouble **overloading operator<<** for use with the **mapped value** in my map:

```
map<string,abs*> _map;
// that my declaration, and I have filled it with keys/values
```

**Ive tried both of these:**

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, abs*& ab) 
{ 
    std::cout << 12345 << std::endl; 
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, abs* ab)
{ 
    std::cout << 12345 << std::endl; 
}
```

In my program I simply call:

```
std::cout << _map["key"] << std::endl; 
// trying to call overloaded operator for mapped value
// instead it always prints the address of the mapped value to screen
```

Ive also tried:

```
std::cout << *_map["key"] << std::endl; 
// trying to call overloaded operator for mapped value
// And that gives me a really long compile time error
```

Anyone know what I could change to get this to output the value of the mapped value, instead of the address?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: can you post a small complete sample ?

Comment: The code you have posted works correctly. The problem lies in the code you *didn't* post. Please reduce your actual program to the smallest complete example that demonstrates the problem. You will, in all likelihood, discover the problem yourself. If not, post the small complete example in your question. See http://sscce.org/.

Comment: Ps. [works for me](http://ideone.com/Ps8Vr).

Comment: You're not returning an ostream from your operator<<

Comment: Are there any namespaces in action? In what namespace is `map<string,abs*> _map;` declaration, `operator<<` declaration and code that uses them?

Comment: Thanks alot, I agree I need to post code. I need to scale it down a bit, that will probably get me to the root of the problem.

Comment: Thanks Rob, I see what you mean, It is an error elsewhere in my code. Im working on finding it. That link is great

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `abs` as a type - `abs` is a function declared in `cstdlib` header. You didn't provide declaration of that type so this example is using some fictive `Abs` type:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct Abs
{
    Abs(int n) : n_(n){}
    int n_;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Abs* p) 
{ 
    os << (*p).n_;
    return os;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::map<std::string, Abs*> map_;
    Abs a1(1);
    Abs a2(2);

    map_["1"] = &Abs(1);
    map_["2"] = &Abs(2);
    std::cout << map_["1"] << ", " << map_["2"] << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
 1, 2
```

Comment: Actually the class is named Abstract, you think that is the problem?

Comment: No, that name is fine. `map_["key"]` is returning a reference to the value which is of the type `Abstract*` in your case. `ostream::operator<<` is overloaded for built-in types (like `int`, `float`...and pointers) so that is why you got address of that object printed in your first call. If you want to display a value of some data member of class `Abstract`, you need to overload `operator<<` either for type `Abstract*` (see my example above) and then to pass `map_["key"]` to it or to overload it for type `Abstract` (which is actually a common practice) and then to pass `*(map_["key"])` to it.

Comment: I appreciate all your help. I found the problem was that my Abstract class did not have the operator<< declared as a friend function. I did not think it had to be declared as a friend because it did not access any private members of that class, however, it did need to be. That made all the difference.

Comment: Thanks Bryan. Yeah, I used struct in the example above and all struct members are `public` by default so `operator<<` could access its members without being its `friend`. For classes is a different story...but you know it now :)